# XSLT not outputting all records

Tags: xml, xslt

Good afternoon

I am trying to select certain nodes from an XML file and output them into a new XML file with a different node structure. I can get this to work fine for an XML file with only one record in it, but when I attempt to run the xslt on a file with 2 distinct records, it outputs 2 copies of the first record.

The xml file I want to transform FROM is:

```
<records>
<rec resultID="1">
  <header>
    <controlInfo>
      <bkinfo>
        <btl>Effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer.</btl>
      </bkinfo>
      <dissinfo/>
      <jinfo>
        <jtl>European Journal of Oncology Nursing</jtl>
        <issn>14623889</issn>
      </jinfo>
      <pubinfo>
        <dt year="2017" month="12" day="01">Dec2017</dt>
        <vid>31</vid>
      </pubinfo>
      <artinfo>
        <ui type="doi">10.1016/j.ejon.2017.08.005</ui>
        <ppf>46</ppf>
        <ppct>6</ppct>
        <formats/>
        <tig>
          <atl>Effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer.</atl>
        </tig>
        <aug>
          <au>Chimluang, Janya</au>
          <au>Thanasilp, Sureeporn</au>
          <au>Akkayagorn, Lanchasak</au>
          <au>Upasen, Ratchaneekorn</au>
          <au>Pudtong, Noppamat</au>
          <au>Tantitrakul, Wilailuck</au>
          <affil>Faculty of Nursing, Chulalongkorn University, Bangkok, Thailand</affil>
        </aug>
        <sug>
          <subj type="major">Terminally Ill Patients</subj>
          <subj type="major">Cancer Patients</subj>
          <subj type="major">Psychological Well-Being</subj>
          <subj type="major">Spiritual Care</subj>
          <subj type="major">Buddhism</subj>
          <subj type="major">Terminal Care</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Human</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Quasi-Experimental Studies</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Pretest-Posttest Design</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Control Group</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Adult</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Middle Age</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Aged</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Psychological Well-Being Evaluation</subj>
          <subj type="age">Adult: 19-44 years</subj>
          <subj type="age">Middle Aged: 45-64 years</subj>
          <subj type="age">Aged: 65+ years</subj>
        </sug>
        <ab>Purpose To evaluate the effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer. Methods This quasi-experimental research study had pre- and post-test control groups. The experimental group received conventional care and an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles for three consecutive days, including seven activities based on precept activities, concentration activities and wisdom activities. The control group received conventional care alone. Results Forty-eight patients participated in this study: 23 in the experimental group and 25 in the control group. Their mean age was 53 (standard deviation 10) years. The spiritual well-being of participants in the experimental group was significantly higher than that of participants in the control group at the second post-test ( P &lt; 0.05). Conclusions An intervention based on basic Buddhist principles improved the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer. This result supports the beneficial effects of implementing this type of intervention for patients with terminal cancer.</ab>
        <pubtype>Academic Journal</pubtype>
        <doctype>research</doctype>
        <doctype>Article</doctype>
      </artinfo>
      <language>English</language>
    </controlInfo>
    <displayInfo>
      <pLink>
        <url>http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=jlh&amp;AN=126392076&amp;site=ehost-live</url>
      </pLink>
    </displayInfo>
  </header>
</rec>
<rec resultID="2">
  <header>
    <controlInfo>
      <bkinfo>
        <btl>Purpose in life in ALS patient-caregiver dyads: A multilevel longitudinal analysis.</btl>
      </bkinfo>
      <dissinfo/>
      <jinfo>
        <jtl>Health Psychology</jtl>
        <issn>02786133</issn>
      </jinfo>
      <pubinfo>
        <dt year="2017" month="11" day="01">Nov2017</dt>
        <vid>36</vid>
        <iid>11</iid>
        <place>Washington, District of Columbia</place>
      </pubinfo>
      <artinfo>
        <ui type="doi">10.1037/hea0000507</ui>
        <ppf>1092</ppf>
        <ppct>13</ppct>
        <formats/>
        <tig>
          <atl>Purpose in life in ALS patient-caregiver dyads: A multilevel longitudinal analysis.</atl>
        </tig>
        <aug>
          <au>Garcia, Natasha E.</au>
          <au>Morey, Jennifer N.</au>
          <au>Kasarskis, Edward J.</au>
          <au>Segerstrom, Suzanne C.</au>
        </aug>
        <sug>
          <subj type="major">Amyotrophic Lateral Sclerosis</subj>
          <subj type="major">Caregivers</subj>
          <subj type="major">Family Relations</subj>
          <subj type="major">Life Purpose</subj>
          <subj type="major">Psychological Well-Being</subj>
          <subj type="major">Disease Progression</subj>
          <subj type="major">Quality of Life</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Human</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Severity of Illness</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Prospective Studies</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Descriptive Research</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Descriptive Statistics</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Quality of Life Evaluation</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Time Factors</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Psychological Well-Being Evaluation</subj>
        </sug>
        <ab>Objective: Eudaemonic positive psychological health (PPH), such as purpose in life (PIL), may be maintained more than hedonic PPH, such as quality of life (QOL), for patients with amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS) and their caregivers across the disease course. Furthermore, patients' and caregivers' PPH may impact one another. The present study examined (a) PIL and QOL variance structures; (b) PIL and QOL trajectories from diagnosis, approaching death, with disease severity; and (c) between-dyad and within-dyad relationships for PIL and QOL in patients with ALS and their caregivers. Method: PIL and QOL were assessed in patient-caregiver dyads (N = 110) up to 7 times over 18 months. Results: Multilevel models revealed the proportion of variance attributed to stable between-person differences was higher for PIL (patients = 74%; caregivers = 76%) than QOL (patients = 60%; caregivers = 55%). PIL and QOL declined in relation to disease severity and time. For PIL, proximity to diagnosis and death moderated within-person change; decline was generally faster following diagnosis and approaching death. Longitudinal within-dyad relationships revealed that patients' fluctuations in PIL were mirrored in their caregiver and vice versa. Conclusions: PIL was more stable than QOL and was therefore a potential psychological resource for patients and caregivers. Critical periods--after diagnosis and approaching death--accompanied more rapid PIL decline. QOL was also impacted by proximity to critical periods. PIL within-dyad relationships may reflect a shared disease experience. Psychological intervention focused on enhancing purpose, particularly during critical periods, is a promising direction for future study.</ab>
        <pubtype>Academic Journal</pubtype>
        <doctype>research</doctype>
        <doctype>Article</doctype>
      </artinfo>
      <language>English</language>
    </controlInfo>
    <displayInfo>
      <pLink>
        <url>http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=jlh&amp;AN=125932785&amp;site=ehost-live</url>
      </pLink>
    </displayInfo>
  </header>
</rec>
</records>
```

The xslt template I am using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <citations>
            <xsl:for-each select="/records/rec">
                <citation>
                    <Author><xsl:value-of select="/records//au"/></Author>
                    <Title><xsl:value-of select="/records//atl"/></Title>
                    <Journal><xsl:value-of select="/records//jtl"/>/Journal>
                    <Year><xsl:value-of select="/records//@year"/></Year>
                    <Volume><xsl:value-of select="/records//vid"/></Volume>
                    <StartPage><xsl:value-of select="/records//ppf"/>/StartPage>
                    <PageCount><xsl:value-of select="/records//ppct"/></PageCount>
                    <Abstract><xsl:value-of select="/records//ab"/></Abstract>
                    <DOI>http://dx.doi.org/<xsl:value-of select="/records//ui"/></DOI>
                    <URL><xsl:value-of select="/records//url"/></URL>
                    <Subjects><xsl:for-each select="/records//subj"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/>, </xsl:for-each></Subjects>
                </citation>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </citations>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I am getting when I run the xslt on the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<citations>
  <citation>
    <Author>Chimluang, Janya</Author>
    <Title>Effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer.</Title>
    <Journal>European Journal of Oncology Nursing</Journal>
    <Year>2017</Year>
    <Volume>31</Volume>
    <StartPage>46</StartPage>
    <PageCount>6</PageCount>
    <Abstract>Purpose To evaluate the effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer. Methods This quasi-experimental research study had pre- and post-test control groups. The experimental group received conventional care and an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles for three consecutive days, including seven activities based on precept activities, concentration activities and wisdom activities. The control group received conventional care alone. Results Forty-eight patients participated in this study: 23 in the experimental group and 25 in the control group. Their mean age was 53 (standard deviation 10) years. The spiritual well-being of participants in the experimental group was significantly higher than that of participants in the control group at the second post-test ( P &lt; 0.05). Conclusions An intervention based on basic Buddhist principles improved the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer. This result supports the beneficial effects of implementing this type of intervention for patients with terminal cancer.</Abstract>
    <DOI>http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ejon.2017.08.005</DOI>
    <URL>http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=jlh&amp;AN=126392076&amp;site=ehost-live</URL>
    <Subjects>Terminally Ill Patients, Cancer Patients, Psychological Well-Being, Spiritual Care, Buddhism, Terminal Care, Human, Quasi-Experimental Studies, Pretest-Posttest Design, Control Group, Adult, Middle Age, Aged, Psychological Well-Being Evaluation, Adult: 19-44 years, Middle Aged: 45-64 years, Aged: 65+ years, Amyotrophic Lateral Sclerosis, Caregivers, Family Relations, Life Purpose, Psychological Well-Being, Disease Progression, Quality of Life, Human, Severity of Illness, Prospective Studies, Descriptive Research, Descriptive Statistics, Quality of Life Evaluation, Time Factors, Psychological Well-Being Evaluation, </Subjects>
  </citation>
  <citation>
    <Author>Chimluang, Janya</Author>
    <Title>Effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer.</Title>
    <Journal>European Journal of Oncology Nursing</Journal>
    <Year>2017</Year>
    <Volume>31</Volume>
    <StartPage>46</StartPage>
    <PageCount>6</PageCount>
    <Abstract>Purpose To evaluate the effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer. Methods This quasi-experimental research study had pre- and post-test control groups. The experimental group received conventional care and an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles for three consecutive days, including seven activities based on precept activities, concentration activities and wisdom activities. The control group received conventional care alone. Results Forty-eight patients participated in this study: 23 in the experimental group and 25 in the control group. Their mean age was 53 (standard deviation 10) years. The spiritual well-being of participants in the experimental group was significantly higher than that of participants in the control group at the second post-test ( P &lt; 0.05). Conclusions An intervention based on basic Buddhist principles improved the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer. This result supports the beneficial effects of implementing this type of intervention for patients with terminal cancer.</Abstract>
    <DOI>http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ejon.2017.08.005</DOI>
    <URL>http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=jlh&amp;AN=126392076&amp;site=ehost-live</URL>
    <Subjects>Terminally Ill Patients, Cancer Patients, Psychological Well-Being, Spiritual Care, Buddhism, Terminal Care, Human, Quasi-Experimental Studies, Pretest-Posttest Design, Control Group, Adult, Middle Age, Aged, Psychological Well-Being Evaluation, Adult: 19-44 years, Middle Aged: 45-64 years, Aged: 65+ years, Amyotrophic Lateral Sclerosis, Caregivers, Family Relations, Life Purpose, Psychological Well-Being, Disease Progression, Quality of Life, Human, Severity of Illness, Prospective Studies, Descriptive Research, Descriptive Statistics, Quality of Life Evaluation, Time Factors, Psychological Well-Being Evaluation, </Subjects>
  </citation>
</citations>
```

As you can see I am getting a duplicate of record 1. I have tried changing the "for-reach select" to several different values with no change, including the rec @resultID.

I am hoping for some guidance on where I am going wrong with the xslt code so that I can produce the unique outputs.

Thank you for your help

Andrew

Comment: It is not clear which output you want if there are several descendants like the `au` elements. In general an `xsl:for-each select="/records/rec"` changes the context node inside of the `for-each` to the `rec` element being processed so paths used inside should be relative to that, like `.//au` or like `descendant::au`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is that you use absolute paths like `/records//au` instead of relative paths like `au` in your `xsl:for-each` loop.
In short: your `xsl:for-each` loop is correct and working, but you don't really use it. A `xsl:for-each` loop sets the *context node* in each iteration to a new value, here the next `rec` node as desired. Then you can relatively refer to this current node with `au`, `atl`, `jtl`...

In the following, changed, template I made use of a `xsl:variable` to shorten the relative paths. And I used only the first of the `au` elements, you can change that according to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <citations>
            <xsl:for-each select="/records/rec">
                <xsl:variable name="hdr" select="header/controlInfo" />
                <citation>
                    <Author><xsl:value-of select="$hdr/artinfo/aug/au[1]"/></Author>
                    <Title><xsl:value-of select="$hdr/artinfo/tig/atl"/></Title>
                    <Journal><xsl:value-of select="$hdr/jinfo/jtl"/></Journal>
                    <Year><xsl:value-of select="$hdr/pubinfo/dt/@year"/></Year>
                    <Volume><xsl:value-of select="$hdr/pubinfo/vid"/></Volume>
                    <StartPage><xsl:value-of select="$hdr/artinfo/ppf"/></StartPage>
                    <PageCount><xsl:value-of select="$hdr/artinfo/ppct"/></PageCount>
                    <Abstract><xsl:value-of select="$hdr/artinfo/ab"/></Abstract>
                    <DOI>http://dx.doi.org/<xsl:value-of select="$hdr/artinfo/ui"/></DOI>
                    <URL><xsl:value-of select="header/displayInfo/pLink/url"/></URL>
                    <Subjects><xsl:for-each select="$hdr/artinfo/sug/subj"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/>, </xsl:for-each></Subjects>
                </citation>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </citations>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It would also be possible to use `.//au`, for example, but specifying the whole path like `header/controlInfo/artinfo/aug/au[1]` is clearer and less error-prone if something is changed. It's merely a matter of choice.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I had tried to use the whole path earlier but I was making a mistake with my starting point. In the meantime I also found another way to get this to work although I don't think it is as pure. It's in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get this to work is to add current() ahead of the location in the value-of select statements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <citations>
            <xsl:for-each select="records/rec">
                <citation>
                    <Author><xsl:value-of select="current()//au"/></Author>
                    <Year><xsl:value-of select="current()//@year"/></Year>
                    <Title><xsl:value-of select="current()//atl"/></Title>
                    <Abstract><xsl:value-of select="current()//ab"/></Abstract>
                    <Journal><xsl:value-of select="current()//jtl"/></Journal>
                    <Volume><xsl:value-of select="current()//vid"/></Volume>
                    <StartPage><xsl:value-of select="current()//ppf"/></StartPage>
                    <PageCount><xsl:value-of select="current()//ppct"/></PageCount>
                    <DOI>http://dx.doi.org/<xsl:value-of select="current()//ui"/></DOI>
                    <URL><xsl:value-of select="current()//url"/></URL>
                    <Subjects><xsl:for-each select="current()//subj"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/>, </xsl:for-each></Subjects>
                </citation>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </citations>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```